# Bent flange below the floor level -what is the proper way to install a flange spacer?

Tags: toilet, flange

My flange is a little bit bent and overall not level.
The result is that an extender won't sit tight on the flange and it is also a not level (higher on one side as you can see in the second picture)
Other than removing the old flange (which is out of question right now) what other options to I have to properly install the flange spacer there?

I am considering either carving the spacer to mold it to the flange on the area where it is bent or shimming it and then adding wax under the white ring to make it air tight. The spacer kit comes with two rings, the one you see there is the 1/2" which if it is shimmed will sit nicely at 2/8" above the floor level.
If chose to carve it then I would need to stack the second ring there as the 1/2" ring will go below the floor level. The advantage of the second method is that I can use the original gasket (taking a bet that it will sit properly on the bent flange below)

Here are some pictures
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is so important to have the toilet flange/flange extender level when the wax ring can compensate for that ? What tolerances are accepted?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/242508/why-is-so-important-to-have-the-toilet-flange-flange-extender-level-when-the-wax)

Comment: no this is about how to tighten the space between the white ring you see in the picture and the flange that is below which is bent

Comment: Is it just that section circle in red that bent?  Not the whole flange?

Comment: yes just that area is bent. I guess it got bent when they tried to excessively tighten the toilet sit OR then somehow tried to remove the toilet from there with the bolt in (bolt stuck and would not come out ??)

Comment: I did not say it was the same question, but does it answer it.

Comment: I have found the metal in these flanges to be fairly malleable. If the metal is raised in only one spot, I've had luck in the past tapping it back into position with a hammer.

Comment: @HoneyDo  beat me to the comment..  would try to carefully debend the flange, with that bend sealing becomes more difficult and bolt might slip out, reducing the sealing also.

Comment: @SolarMike No as I explained it does not

Comment: @crip659 and HoneyDo this is cast iron, a magnet does not stick to it so I think I need to just use a thicker rubber gasket that will get compressed more in that area